# IF with timestamp bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to add an attribute that indicates if that version is an original or copy. If is the first version of the site, is original, it is not, is a copy.

the table:

```
id_site  id_version timestamp_version
1        5589       2/3/2022
1        2030       10/7/2022
1        1560       10/8/2022
2        6748       2/3/2022
2        7890       2/4/2022
3        4532       2/3/2022
```

The expected result:

```
id_site id_version  timestamp_version   type_version
1       5589        2/3/2022            original
1       2030        10/7/2022           copy
1       1560        10/8/2022           copy
2       6748        2/3/2022            original
2       7890        2/4/2022            copy
3       4532        2/3/2022            original
```

Comment: I think the following would get you in the ballpark: `CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_site ORDER BY timestamp_version ASC) = 1 THEN 'copy' ELSE 'original' END`

Comment: @JNevill could you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: Happy to hear that did the trick. I don't use bigquery, so I didn't know if there was a more bigquery-esque way of doing this, but it does seem to fit the bill, and it's portable to nearly any other RDBMS should you move off GCP at some point in the future. Added as an answer, @EduardoOrtiz

Comment: @JNevill Thank you for doing that, just up voted your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `IF` or `CASE` here. They are mostly interchangeable, but my preference is `CASE` since it's portable to nearly any other RDBMS where `IF` is only supported in a few.

```
 CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_site ORDER BY timestamp_version ASC) = 1 THEN 'copy' ELSE 'original' END
```

Inside the `CASE` expression we do a ROW_NUMBER() window function will "window" or partition each row in the result set by `id_site` and number each record for each distinct `id_site` sequentially ordered by `timestamp_version` in ascending order. We test to see if that `ROW_NUMBER()` is `1` and then label it with `original` or `copy`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a window function in an if statement for that:

```sql
with test as (

    select * from unnest([
        struct(1 as id_site, 5589 as id_version, timestamp(date "2022-03-02") as timestamp_version),               
            (1, 2030, timestamp(date "2022-07-10")),
            (1, 1560, timestamp(date "2022-08-10")),
            (2, 6748, timestamp(date "2022-03-02")),
            (2, 7890, timestamp(date "2022-04-02")),
            (3, 4532, timestamp(date "2022-03-02"))
    ])
)

select 
    *,
    IF(timestamp_version = min(timestamp_version) over (partition by id_site), "original", "copy") AS type_version 
from test
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below option

```
select *,
  if(lag(id_version) over prev is null, 'original', 'copy') type_version,
from your_table
window prev as (partition by id_site order by timestamp_version)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]